# LINQ-SQL Updating Multiple Rows in a single transaction

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I need help re-factoring this legacy LINQ-SQL code which is generating around 100 update statements.

I'll keep playing around with the best solution, but would appreciate some ideas/past experience with this issue.

Here's my code:

```
List<Foo> foos;
int userId = 123;

using (DataClassesDataContext db = new FooDatabase())
{
     foos = (from f in db.FooBars
             where f.UserId = userId
             select f).ToList();

     foreach (FooBar fooBar in foos)
     {
         fooBar.IsFoo = false;
     }

     db.SubmitChanges()
}
```

Essentially i want to update the `IsFoo` field to false for all records that have a particular `UserId` value.

Whats happening is the `.ToList()` is firing off a query to get all the `FooBars` for a particular user, then for each Foo object, its executing an `UPDATE` statement updating the `IsFoo` property.

Can the above code be re-factored to one single `UPDATE` statement?

Ideally, the only SQL i want fired is the below:

```
UPDATE FooBars
SET    IsFoo = FALSE
WHERE  UserId = 123
```

---

**EDIT**

Ok so looks like it cant be done without using db.ExecuteCommand.

Grr...!

What i'll probably end up doing is creating another extension method for the `DLINQ` namespace. Still require some hardcoding (ie writing "WHERE" and "UPDATE"), but at least it hides most of the implementation details away from the actual LINQ query syntax.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in a single transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check DataClassesDataContext.ExecuteCommand...

Comment: i saw some examples of that - but doesnt that involve "hardcoding" the SQL as a string and passing that to the ExecuteCommand method? 

Thought the whole point of LINQ-SQL was to abstract away the underlying details of the database.

Comment: You're right. Only reason here is performance. No need to get all data to your app, and back just for simple update. If you have more than 100 entities difference will be very big...

Comment: Yep - only way to go it seems.

I was saddened to see this problem also exists in EF.